# c# SSL GET and POST request

Tags: c#, .net, http, ssl, https

I am trying to make GET and POST requests by using SSL and self signed certificate to HTTPS sites, I want my program to get GET and POST requests from the browser and open this SSL with self signed cert, actually I want the HTML source code of the https site, here for example I used twitter:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     string host = "twitter.com";

     // Connect socket
     TcpClient client = new TcpClient(host, 443);
     NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

     // Wrap in SSL stream
     SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(stream, false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate));
     sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host);

     //Build request
     var sb = new StringBuilder();
     sb.AppendLine("GET / HTTP/1.1");
     sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Host: {0}", host));
     sb.AppendLine("Connection: keep-alive");
     sb.AppendLine("User-Agent: CSharp");
     sb.AppendLine("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
     sb.AppendLine("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch");
     sb.AppendLine("Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8");
     sb.AppendLine("Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
     sb.AppendLine();

     //Go go go!
     byte[] headerBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
     sslStream.Write(headerBytes, 0, headerBytes.Length);
     sslStream.Flush();

     //Get a place to put it
     byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
     int bytes;

     //Answer
     do
     {
         bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
         Console.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));
     } while (bytes != 0);

     //And done
     client.Close();
     Console.ReadKey();

}

public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
```

The response I get to the console is:

```
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 0
date: Sun, 26 Jun 2016 15:11:54 GMT
location: https://mobile.twitter.com/
server: tsa_f
set-cookie: guest_id=v1%3A146695391459213782; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 26-Jun-2018 15:11:54 UTC
status: 307 Temporary Redirect
strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519
x-connection-hash: b644a95971e954e39bc0f563f88d51d6
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-response-time: 93
x-transaction: 000570e300d30436
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

How can I get the HTML source code of a HTTPS site using SSL and self signed certificate?

Comment: Notice that the response code is 307 `Temporary Redirect`. Follow the redirect specified by the `location` response header like the 307 tells you to. And don't forget about the cookies that the server is asking you to set.

Comment: Use `HttpClient` or `WebClient` instead of `SslStream` etc, they can handle certificates and auto redirects.

Comment: thanks, how can I use self signed certificate in WebClient or HttpClient?

Comment: HTTP communication is usually a conversation, so as other comments indicated you either switch to another way (so that automatically redirection is processed) or handle such redirection and other responses on your own. Since Twitter uses only server side certificate, your self signed certificate is useless.